# Recursive sum over two variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, recursion, dplyr

I have two columns with values, a and b. I want to add a third column c, which is (at row i) the sum from 0 to i of b plus the sum from 0 to (i-1) of c, multiplied with a, i.e.

```
c_i = (sum_i (b) + sum_(i-1) (c) ) * a_i
```

I tried

```
data %>%
mutate(
 c = a * (cumsum(b) + lag(cumsum(c), default = 0))
)
```

However this doesn't work, as I am just creating c based on values of c that don't exist at the moment:

> ```
> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `c`.
> x object 'c' not found
> ```

Previously I handled such problems using for-loops. However, I got used to dplyr, and there is always a way. However, I do not get it.

I am grateful for any help!

edit: In a previous version I was inaccurate, as a is also a vector, not a constant. I changed it in the formula

The desired output:

```
row 1: 0.5 * (7  + 0 ) =3.5

row 2: 0.3 * (7+1 + 3.5) = 3.45

row 3: 1.0 * (7+1+9 + 3.5+3.45) = 23.95

| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
|0.5|7|3.5|
|0.3|1|3.45|
|1|9|23.95|
|0.2|10|...|
```

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: like this? `structure(list(a = c(0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8), b = c(7L, 1L, 
9L, 10L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: `a` also refers to each value of `a` in row `i` right? And it would be helpful to show your desired output too.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the remark. I changed it in the formula. Further, I added a table with the desired output. I hope it became clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I would have done it in similar [fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68738205/2884859) like @27phi9.  You may, however, do this without writing any function before hand.  I am giving you three approaches (i) baseR, (ii) dplyr only, (iii) dplyr + purrr

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8), b = c(7L, 1L,  9L, 10L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

transform(df, C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                                  seq(nrow(df)), 
                                  init = 0, 
                                  accumulate = TRUE)[-1]})
#>     a  b       C
#> 1 0.5  7  3.5000
#> 2 0.3  1  3.4500
#> 3 1.0  9 23.9500
#> 4 0.2 10 11.5800
#> 5 0.4  3 28.9920
#> 6 0.8  2 82.7776
```

---

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                             seq(nrow(df)), 
                             init = 0, 
                             accumulate = TRUE)[-1]})
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       a     b     C
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1   0.5     7  3.5 
#> 2   0.3     1  3.45
#> 3   1       9 24.0 
#> 4   0.2    10 11.6 
#> 5   0.4     3 29.0 
#> 6   0.8     2 82.8
```

---

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(C = {x <- 0; unlist(accumulate2(cumsum(b), a, .init = 0, ~ {x <<- ..1 + x; (..2 + x) * ..3 }))[-1]})
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       a     b     C
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1   0.5     7  3.5 
#> 2   0.3     1  3.45
#> 3   1       9 24.0 
#> 4   0.2    10 11.6 
#> 5   0.4     3 29.0 
#> 6   0.8     2 82.8
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding.  I already upvoted yours but I am yet to understand that!

Answer (score 4):

## Update

A super efficient option is by solving the a linear matrix (thank @Martin Gal for comments):

```
transform(
  df,
  C = solve(
    `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
    a * cumsum(b)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    a  b       C
1 0.5  7  3.5000
2 0.3  1  3.4500
3 1.0  9 23.9500
4 0.2 10 11.5800
5 0.4  3 28.9920
6 0.8  2 82.7776
```

---

or in a `dplyr` manner

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    C = solve(
      `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
      a * cumsum(b)
    )
  )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      a     b     C
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1   0.5     7  3.5
2   0.3     1  3.45
3   1       9 24.0
4   0.2    10 11.6
5   0.4     3 29.0
6   0.8     2 82.8
```

## Previous answer (Recursion approach, ***INFFICIENT***)

---

A base R option (but ***inefficient***) by defining a recursion function `f`

```
f <- function(k) {
  if (k == 1) {
    return(with(df[k, ], a * b))
  }
  r <- f(k - 1)
  c(r, with(df, a[k] * (sum(b[1:k]) + sum(r))))
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(nrow(df))
[1]  3.5000  3.4500 23.9500 11.5800 28.9920 82.7776
```

and

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(C = f(n()))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      a     b     C
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1   0.5     7  3.5
2   0.3     1  3.45
3   1       9 24.0
4   0.2    10 11.6
5   0.4     3 29.0
6   0.8     2 82.8
```

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, you are right, This is not efficient. The best way is to use `for` loop and iterate by rows. I just provide an option in case of small dataset.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut See my update if you want a efficient solution.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: Don't know, if it's more effizient, but you can spare the `replace()` function: `\`diag<-\`(mat <- matrix(-df$a, length(df$a), length(df$a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)`

Comment: @MartinGal Good idea. I think yours is more efficient since using logical matrix as a mask is more straightforward. I updated my code as per your advice.

Comment: There are still a few concerns, but +1 for the originality. Note that solving a triangular system is still O(n^2) in both time and space, while the direct loop is O(n). But thanks to solve calling compiled routines, it may still be fast.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, as I said before, `for` loop is the most efficient way here. but it seems OP wants something else instead of `for` loop.

Comment: The closest to dplyr's philosophy is 27 ϕ 9's solution. Yours relates to time series in an insightful way. I chose the dumb way: it's just a loop, do it in a language that likes loops. All have pros and cons.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can achieve this is with a custom function that relies on `purrr::accumulate2()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

f <- function(a, b) {
  b <- cumsum(b)
  x_cum <- 0
  unlist(accumulate2(a, b, ~ {
    x_cum <<- ..1 + x_cum
    ..2 * (..3 + x_cum)
  }, .init = 0))[-1]
}



df %>%
  mutate(c = f(a, b))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1   0.5     7  3.5 
2   0.3     1  3.45
3   1       9 24.0 
4   0.2    10 11.6 
5   0.4     3 29.0 
6   0.8     2 82.8
```

Comment: I think it should be `res <- y * (z + x_cum)`. `purrr::accumulate2` is indeed a way, however I'd be reluctant to use it if there are many rows. It's almost certainly worse than a for loop, as there is the additional cost of function calls. Always the tradeoff between simplicity, elegance and speed.

Comment: Ah, yes, right, I messed up with the variable names and the fact the `x` argument is the *previous* accumulated value. My comment holds if you swap the two assignments in the function.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut - ah, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it's just simpler to do it in C.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("NumericVector custom_cumsum(double a, NumericVector b) {
  int n = b.size();
  NumericVector c(n);
  double sb = 0, sc = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sb += b[i];
    sc += (c[i] = a * (sb + sc));
  }
  return c;
}")

custom_cumsum(1.0, 1:10)
```

If `a` is also a vector:

```
cppFunction("NumericVector custom_cumsum(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
  int n = b.size();
  NumericVector c(n);
  double sb = 0, sc = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sb += b[i];
    sc += (c[i] = a[i] * (sb + sc));
  }
  return c;
}")

custom_cumsum(rep(1, 10), 1:10)

custom_cumsum(c(0.5, 0.3, 1, 0.2),
              c(7, 1, 9, 10))
# result: 3.50  3.45 23.95 11.58
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In R, you can do it a similar way using a for-loop. However, I wondered whether it is also possible using dplyr.

Comment: @C.Sebastian I don't think it's possible with dplyr, but even if it is, it will likely be slow as I do not see why a vectorized function would have been cooked up to do exactly this. Maybe in a time series package? When you need nonstandard computations that require previous values, the best is **not** doing it in R directly. And with Rcpp, it's almost trivial to get a fast function that fits precisely your needs, and that is directly usable in R.

Comment: The downside: you need some skills in `C`. Since I'm lacking those skills, I don't know, what `+=` does and why something like `sc += (c[i] = a[i] * (sb + sc))` even works. Using `C` to solve a problem in `R` is some kind of the next level after the next level. At least for me. :-)

Comment: @MartinGal I can understand that. Take this as an invitation ;) `x += y` is the equivalent of R's `x <- x + y`. And you could guess the other one as it works in R too: an assignment can be used inside an expression, and its value is simply the assigned value. So it's a shortcut for, again in R, `c[[i]] <- a[[i]] * (sb + sc)` followed by `sc <- sc + c[[i]]`.

Comment: I put it on my list. I need to dive into `R` further before trying to learn another language. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit **off-topic**, but I did a benchmark of all solutions shown here. I took the solutions as shown in the answers, the only renaming 27 ϕ 9's function  to `g`.

```r
library(microbenchmark)

library(Rcpp)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

microbenchmark(
  f_TIC_1 = transform(
    df,
    c = solve(
      `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
      a * cumsum(b)
    )
  ),
  f_TIC_2 = df %>%
    mutate(
      c = solve(
        `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
        a * cumsum(b)
      )
    ),
  f_TIC_3 = df %>% mutate(c = f(n())),
  f_27p9  = df %>% mutate(c = g(a, b)),
  f_AnG_1 = transform(df, C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                                              seq(nrow(df)), 
                                              init = 0, 
                                              accumulate = TRUE)[-1]}),
  f_AnG_2 = df %>%
    mutate(C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                               seq(nrow(df)), 
                               init = 0, 
                               accumulate = TRUE)[-1]}),
  f_AnG_3 = df %>%
    mutate(C = {x <- 0; unlist(accumulate2(cumsum(b), a, .init = 0, ~ {x <<- ..1 + x; (..2 + x) * ..3 }))[-1]}),
  f_JCA  = df$c <- custom_cumsum(df$a, df$b),
  times = 10000
)
```

This gives us a clear winner:

```r
Unit: microseconds
    expr    min     lq       mean median     uq     max neval
 f_TIC_1  169.8  194.2  229.09701  204.6  216.8 68505.6 10000
 f_TIC_2 1314.2 1372.3 1500.52929 1384.1 1415.0  9688.8 10000
 f_TIC_3 1360.6 1429.7 1557.12813 1442.8 1476.0  8486.1 10000
  f_27p9 1351.8 1402.4 1553.47802 1415.4 1446.9 68681.4 10000
 f_AnG_1  143.2  166.8  187.83451  174.5  184.6  4446.3 10000
 f_AnG_2 1337.8 1395.4 1532.25551 1407.1 1439.5 64981.6 10000
 f_AnG_3 1371.0 1428.1 1550.83456 1441.3 1474.0 10439.1 10000
   f_JCA   48.0   71.6   79.39209   76.3   82.3  5544.4 10000
```

@Jean-Claude Arbaut's custom `C` function ranks first in performance, followed by @AnilGoyal's `transform`-`Reduce`-solution and @ThomasIsCoding's `transform`-`solve`-`matrix` way ranking third place.
The `tidyverse`-solutions are quite inefficient and they take the same time as @ThomasIsCoding's "Recursion approach, INFFICIENT!!!!111".

### Edit

Thanks to 27 ϕ 9's comment, I made another example using a data.frame of length 1000

```r
set.seed(2^13)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(a = runif(n), 
                 b = sample(1:n, n, replace = TRUE))
```

The first and interesting insight: the `transform`-`solve`-`matrix` solutions refuse to work returning an error

> Error in solve.default(`diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), :
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number

So I removed those solutions from the benchmark:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # f_TIC_1 = transform(
  #   df,
  #   c = solve(
  #     `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
  #     a * cumsum(b)
  #   )
  # ),
  # f_TIC_2 = df %>%
  #   mutate(
  #     c = solve(
  #       `diag<-`(mat <- matrix(-a, length(a), length(a)), 1) * lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE),
  #       a * cumsum(b)
  #     )
  #   ),
  f_TIC_3 = df %>%  mutate(c = f(n())),
  f_27p9  = df %>% mutate(c = g(a, b)),
  f_AnG_1 = transform(df, C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                                              seq(nrow(df)), 
                                              init = 0, 
                                              accumulate = TRUE)[-1]}),
  f_AnG_2 = df %>%
    mutate(C = {x <- 0; Reduce(function(.x, .y){x <<- .x + x; (cumsum(b)[[.y]] + x) * a[[.y]]}, 
                               seq(nrow(df)), 
                               init = 0, 
                               accumulate = TRUE)[-1]}),
  f_AnG_3 = df %>%
    mutate(C = {x <- 0; unlist(accumulate2(cumsum(b), a, .init = 0, ~ {x <<- ..1 + x; (..2 + x) * ..3 }))[-1]}),
  f_JCA  = df$c <- custom_cumsum(df$a, df$b),
  times = 10000
)
```

This returns

```r
Unit: microseconds
    expr    min      lq        mean  median      uq     max neval
 f_TIC_3 8880.6 9264.65 10369.56781 9401.40 9632.55 93771.1 10000
  f_27p9 3765.4 4050.80  4549.94921 4140.95 4259.25 80884.8 10000
 f_AnG_1 3494.1 3670.70  4050.70616 3724.50 3812.10 83652.8 10000
 f_AnG_2 5296.8 5603.70  6128.01699 5688.20 5803.85 82966.1 10000
 f_AnG_3 3966.5 4249.30  4732.57000 4340.15 4459.40 85970.4 10000
   f_JCA   11.3   23.00    25.84787   26.20   27.20  6148.9 10000
```

The next benchmark I did was using

```r
set.seed(2^14)

n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(a = runif(n), 
                 b = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE))
```

This time `f_TIC_3` refused to run yielding

> Error: C stack usage  15923184 is too close to the limit

Using a recursive function on large datasets doesn't seem to be an effective approach. I reduced the `times` argument from 10_000 to 1_000.

```r
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq        mean    median        uq      max neval
  f_27p9  29822.6  33721.1  38248.6520  37433.10  40815.25 120926.6  1000
 f_AnG_1 184626.9 198480.4 212004.0363 213608.10 218590.20 301492.9  1000
 f_AnG_2 195530.7 211344.4 223346.3003 224671.55 229813.65 306081.5  1000
 f_AnG_3  31657.3  35657.6  39882.8815  39256.85  42544.60 121925.6  1000
   f_JCA     49.5     65.7     75.9027     67.40     69.50   4818.2  1000
```

So, still Jean-Claude Arbaut's `C`-function wins a gold medal.

Comment: Interesting to benchmark but there's very limited value in using a 6 row dataset - most of the time taken will be function overheads and it reveals nothing about how the solutions might scale.

Comment: Good point. I'll build a larger dataframe, still learning and often missing the obvious flaws...